# Docker file - Build failing due to GitHub/SSH issue

Tags: python, git, docker, github

I'm working with an inherited Docker file and I myself am rather new to Docker. I'll do my best in providing the details needed, but let me know if more is needed. I have confirmed I have SSH configured appropriately with GitHub. I have an env variable[3] that is used to call the DockerFile[2] which is using requirements.txt[1] to download and install, among other things, a GitHub package. When this runs I'm presented with the error[4]

```
#17 5.281 Permission denied (publickey).

#17 5.282 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to troubleshoot? I have tried several things (tried different users/machines to confirm nothing wrong w/ SSH<>GitHub, tried different versions of Python 3.x. I'm kind of at a loss at this point. Thanks in advance!

[1]requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-bigquery
pandas
pandas-gbq
cryptography
git+ssh://git@github.com/pendo-io/analytics-projects.git#egg=etl&subdirectory=etl
```

[2]DockerFile

```
# this is our first build stage, it will not persist in the final image
FROM python:3.7.3 as intermediate

# install git
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

# add credentials on build
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# make sure your domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts


COPY requirements.txt /
# download packages
WORKDIR /pip-packages/
RUN pip download -r /requirements.txt



# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.7.3

# copy downloaded packages
WORKDIR /pip-packages/
COPY --from=intermediate /pip-packages/ /pip-packages/
# install packages
# RUN rm -r /pip-packages/src
RUN pip install --no-index --find-links=/pip-packages/ /pip-packages/*

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt


# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD []
```

[3]environment variable

```
update_image () {                                            
        docker build --force-rm -t gcr.io/pendo-reporting/$IMAGE\:latest --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519)" .;\
        docker push gcr.io/pendo-reporting/$IMAGE\:latest
}
```

[4]Last few lines of log

```
 => ERROR [intermediate 11/11] RUN pip download -r /requirements.txt                                                                                                 5.7s
------
 > [intermediate 11/11] RUN pip download -r /requirements.txt:
#17 1.797 Collecting google-cloud-storage (from -r /requirements.txt (line 1))
#17 2.172   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/75/78ed0d1ef691592b94e7a3d9f58153298166486342a97df82d3c5b66cc16/google_cloud_storage-1.38.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103kB)
#17 2.211   Saved ./google_cloud_storage-1.38.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.223 Collecting google-cloud-bigquery (from -r /requirements.txt (line 2))
#17 2.388   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/dd/fed5cb5aa4ddd36cddf17ac2f047b5bbe94a8fbaafcec36e3ef8a692d1fe/google_cloud_bigquery-2.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (221kB)
#17 2.442   Saved ./google_cloud_bigquery-2.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.482 Collecting pandas (from -r /requirements.txt (line 3))
#17 3.014   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/51/48f3fc47c4e2144da2806dfb6629c4dd1fa3d5a143f9652b141e979a8ca9/pandas-1.2.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.9MB)
#17 4.103   Saved ./pandas-1.2.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
#17 4.115 Collecting pandas-gbq (from -r /requirements.txt (line 4))
#17 4.186   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/bd/7178c52d1c19d577bc972c80d2486541631794a5ed8c8f5178a26d61c1be/pandas_gbq-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 4.193   Saved ./pandas_gbq-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 4.205 Collecting cryptography (from -r /requirements.txt (line 5))
#17 4.821   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/9d/aa507ddc5dc630b499d4905000b17448a969f0cdcdb9bbc2fe5e369a5fad/cryptography-3.4.7-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (3.1MB)
#17 5.041   Saved ./cryptography-3.4.7-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 5.081 Collecting etl from git+ssh://git@github.com/pendo-io/analytics-projects.git#egg=etl&subdirectory=etl (from -r /requirements.txt (line 6))
#17 5.082   Cloning ssh://git@github.com/pendo-io/analytics-projects.git to /tmp/pip-download-ftk1hsk_/etl
#17 5.083   Running command git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/pendo-io/analytics-projects.git /tmp/pip-download-ftk1hsk_/etl
#17 5.180   Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.3' to the list of known hosts.
#17 5.281   Permission denied (publickey).
#17 5.282   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#17 5.282 
#17 5.282   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#17 5.283   and the repository exists.
#17 5.355 ERROR: Command "git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/pendo-io/analytics-projects.git /tmp/pip-download-ftk1hsk_/etl" failed with error code 128 in None
#17 5.599 WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 21.1.1 is available.
#17 5.599 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
```

Comment: You chmod the ssh key, but maybe you need to chmod the [.ssh folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder)

Comment: https://github.com/pendo-io/analytics-projects  has a 404 which makes me think this project doesnt exist

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It is a private repo and we do have an SSH key that has permissions to the repo to pull.

Comment: you could try using some `-vvv` flag on your git pull that should give more info about which key its trying to use (try just `git pull <repo>` inside the docker instead of pip install

Comment: You might try adding a command to directly git clone the repo, using the GIT_SSH env variable to set ssh to verbose. Then you should be able to see how it is interacting with the ssh keys. :edit: What Joran Beasley said...

Comment: ahh @xdgmoore thats a probably even better than my suggestion to try git pull with -vvvv

Comment: Actually, you might get everything you need from running `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com`

Comment: Also,  is it valid to put ARG and RUN commands on the same line like that? But maybe that is just a stackoverflow formatting thing...

Comment: It's almost always best to do all GitHub accesses *before* firing up a docker instance. This completely sidesteps the issue of sticking ssh keys *into* the docker instance (which is good because if you stick them in, they're exposed!).

Comment: Thank you @torek for that pointer.  We'll definitely take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution to this was actually rather simple in the end.  After doing a lot of validation on the SSH connection we determined the issue was with `RUN pip download -r /requirements.txt` and instead when we changed the command to `RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt` everything ran fine.  Thank you all for the helpful and constructive pointers.